# Solving proof by induction row

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Hello i am not able to figure out how to continue on this induction.

I did work so far:

[image]

What to do after that?

UPDATED: so far:

[image]

is it right?? but what about k + 1 it doesnt hold for 2^k

Comment: The case $n=1,2$ is trivial, you don't need induction for that. Assuming that with $a_n$ you mean $P(n)$, the next step would be to substitute your induction hypothesis for $a_k+2a_{k-1}$.

Comment: So u mean that i need to put 2^k-1 in a_k+2a_{k-1} ?

Comment: Yes. (comment too short)

Comment: but what abt k + 1? 2^k dont holds for k+1

Comment: Do we really need induction? After having shown this holds for $n=1,2,3$ which is trivial it's just basic algebra: $2^{k} = a_{k-1} + 2a_{k-2} = 2^{k-1} + 2 \cdot 2^{k-2} = \dots = 2^k$

Comment: I should to show it by induction it's a requirement. But yea i can see it can be done much easier with basic algebra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the cases $n=1,2$ you can do by hand.

For $n\geq 3$ you start with the base case as you did. Then you should use **strong induction** (aka complete induction). This means your induction hypothesis assumes that $P(k)=P(k-1)+2P(k-2)$ is true for all $k$ **less than or equal to** $n$ (and $k\geq 3$), rather than just for $k=n$.

Then $P(n+1)=2^{(n+1)-1}=2^n=2^{n-1}+2\cdot 2^{n-2}=P(n)+2P(n-1)$, where you used the induction hypothesis in the last step. Hence you showed the statement is true for $k=n+1$ as well, so it holds for all $k\geq 3$.